# Throw two exceptions at the same time

Tags: java, exception, division

I have the following java method

```
public static double realDivision(Integer num, Double denom) {
  double result = 0.0;
  try{
      result=(double)num/(double)denom;
  }
  catch (ArithmeticException e){
    System.err.println("Smart up Goof");
    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
  }
  return result;

}
```

What I am trying to achieve here is for exceptions to be more descriptive. How can I get Java to smart up a bit and throw a NullPointerException when the one of the numbers are null, and throw something like undefined number exception when both inputs equal zero. It should also be more expressive about divide by zero with a non-zero numerator. How do I do all that?

EDITED
I don't want a bunch of conditionals, like null checks or checks for zero. I was hoping Java knows why the arithmetic exception or NPE occurred and and throw that precise exception. If I can make java do that I get to write the error handling code the way it should be.

Comment: You can write your own exceptions and then manually throw those...

Comment: You can't increase smartness of Java. you will have to code for that.

Comment: Also to point out, two exceptions are not thrown at same time, only one of those will be thrown

Comment: What do you need more precise exceptions for? What are you planning to do with it? If it is just to print a better message, you can do it in your catch{..}

Comment: Lol at getting java to smart up!

Comment: @azzurroverde So that I can write an error handling mechanism based on what gets thrown. If java knows what caused the exception, why is it not being more specific about it.

Comment: @jbx Didn't quite get the joke. :-(

Comment: You will never have an exception if you use double or other floating point numbers. If you cast your number to (int) instead of (double), you will get the exception.

Comment: @Lee No joke on you don't worry. Once you start to understand Java's design principles you will start to realise that compared to some other languages Java is already quite 'smart'. It does not mean it knows what you want to do and certain things also depend on your design choices. For example if you just want to do an arithmetic operation why don't you use `int` and `double`? Java's Autoboxing feature will automatically convert from `Integer` and `Double`. Also, as your program becomes larger you'll find that overdoing a method with lots of exceptions becomes a bit of a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: [Go through this "Throwing multiple exceptions in Java"][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29225574/4705950

Answer (score 1):

You need to distinguish between the two variables being null and the **value** being zero.
If you run your program like this, where the two variables are null, you have the exception you wanted:

```
public class Arithmetics {      
      public static double realDivision(Integer num, Double denom) {
          double result = 0.0;
          try{
              result=(double)num/(double)denom;
          }
          catch (ArithmeticException e){
            System.err.println("Smart up Goof");
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
          }
          return result;

        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        double results=Arithmetics.realDivision(null, null);
        System.out.println(results);

    }

}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Arithmetics.realDivision(Arithmetics.java:7)
    at Arithmetics.main(Arithmetics.java:19)
```

**EDITED**
And ... if you use values

```
double results=Arithmetics.realDivision(new Integer(0), new Double(0));
```

the results are

```
NaN
```

if you use

```
double results=Arithmetics.realDivision(new Integer(1), new Double(0));
```

The results are

```
infinite
```

Comment: And if you want to deal with the problem, use logic ***before*** the division. For example if(num.intValue()==0){} ...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by simply adding checks inside the `try - catch` block.
Something like:

```
if ((num == null) || (denum == null))
{
   throw new NullPointerException("Argument is null");
}
```

However I should be a bit wary of using unchecked exceptions like that, since they will bubble up your stack without forcing the caller to catch it.

Maybe creating your own exception and declaring your method to throw it would be better.

**UPDATED** after question was edited.

Why not simply change it to this:

```
public static double realDivision(int num, double denom) 
{
  return (double) num / denom;    
}
```

The parameters are now primitives not Objects, so they cannot be `null`. The arguments you pass to the function can still be instances of `Integer` and `Double`, and Java's Autoboxing feature will do the translation for you (throwing an `Exception` if they are `null`).

The only check you need to do manually in this case if you want to is whether the `denom` is `0`. Its because in the case of `double` Java returns Infinity rather than throwing an `ArithmeticException`, because in reality that is the answer and its useful in certain double precision calculations. If you were using integers you would get the `ArithmeticException`.

Answer (score 0):

Java already throws two different exceptions, not at the same time, but according to which one occurs. Maybe you mean how to catch two possibly different exceptions? 
Like for example:

```
public static double realDivision(Integer num, Double denom) {
          double result = 0.0;
          try{
              if(num.intValue()==0){

              }
              result=(double)num/(double)denom;
          }
          catch (ArithmeticException e){
            System.err.println("Smart up Goof");
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
          }
          catch (NullPointerException e){
                System.err.println("One of the numbers is null. I am smart. Java");
                e.printStackTrace(System.err);
              }
          return result;

        }
```

Note however that in this case ArithmeticException will not be thrown because you are using floating points. If you use integer, you will have the exception.