# Throw a Composite Exception in Java

Tags: java, exception

I'm using `ExecutorService`, `Future` and `Callable` to do parallel processing. Though the `Callable`'s exception can be caught when invoking `Future#get`, how to catch all the exceptions thrown by all callables and then throw a huge, compound exception, like:

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
List<Future<Void>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<Void>>();
futures.add(service.submit(new TaskA());
futures.add(service.submit(new TaskB());

for (Future<Void> future : futures) {
    try {
        future.get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ???
    }
}

// throw the big exception here

service.shutdown();
```

Comment: If you catch an Exception, add it to a `List`.

Comment: use array of `exception`?

Comment: Just like Sotirios has suggested, declare a List of Exceptions and add caught Exceptions to the list in the catch block.  Then you'll probably want to _return_ the List rather than _throwing_ a _composite Exception_.

Comment: Maybe you can use an exception handler: [setUncaughtExceptionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler))

Comment: If you really want to throw something, you _could_ do something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2912638/778118).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis A list of exceptions cannot be 'catched', so it loses the function of exception, IMHO.

Comment: You aren't catching a `List` of exceptions. You are instantiating a `List`, iterating over all the `futures`, calling `get()` on each one, and adding any caught `Exception` to the `List`. You then use that `List` in a custom `CompositeException` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but

```
public class CompositeException extends Exception {
    private List<Exception> exceptions = new ArrayList<Exception>();
    public List<Exception> getExceptions() {
        return exceptions;
    }
}
```

Instantiate one of these puppies and load it up with all the exceptions before throwing it.

Comment: What will happen when you print the stack trace of this exception?  Or view its message?

Comment: @therealmitchconnors nothing useful. You could override the methods of `Exception` to output all stacktraces, all messages, etc of the exceptions.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to associate multiple exceptions with a single throw, use `addSuppressed` on your outermost exception.

It won't help you much on the catch side, but comprehensive error handling is never easy, especially after joining multiple threads of control.